# ConnectionPoolTimeOutException while using AWS SDK for S3 Download

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am fetching S3 objects via a Completion Service (Fixed Thread Pool of Size 20).

Below is the code being triggered via completionService.submit()

```
    private Pair<File, ObjectMetadata> downloadObject() {

    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey);

    StringBuilder localPathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    localPathBuilder.append(root).append(File.separator).append("input").append(File.separator).append(bucketName)
            .append(File.separator).append(objectKey);
    //System.out.println("File is being downloaded to : " + localPathBuilder.toString());
    File file = new File(localPathBuilder.toString());
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3Client.getObject(request, file);
    
    if(objectMetadata != null) {
        objectMetadata.setContentEncoding("gzip");
    }

    return new Pair<File, ObjectMetadata>(file, objectMetadata);
}
```

Basis of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-java.io.File-), the connection should have been automatically closed after object is downloaded. But the error suggests that connections are not getting closed properly.

Hence, I did try the suggestions in this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405) and fiddled with socket timeout and max connections.

```
private static final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withMaxConnections(100).withSocketTimeout(1000*1000))
        .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true).build();
```

However, the issue persists and I still get a `ConnectionPoolTimeoutException`

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy10.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    ... 22 more
```